# Undefined subroutine &main::header called at /opt/alu-rp/www/cgi/munin-cgi-html

Tags: perl, cgi, munin

I am facing the error "Undefined subroutine &main::header called at /opt/alu-rp/www/cgi/munin-cgi-html line 54." while opening the munin page(http://localhost/munin)

Perl version: v5.32.0
Munin version: v2.0.65

With the error, able to see the header is not initiated due to the new condition added in munin-cgi-html

```
# grab config
html_startup(\@params);
while(new CGI::Fast){
    print header("text/html");
    $config = get_config(1);
    show_page();
}
:
:
# CGI in perl 5.20 is now seriously broken as it doesn't import into the namespace.
# So we have to delegate explicitly. It's easier than prefixing with CGI:: each use.
# This workaround is applied only if "header" is undefined (i.e. for perl >= 5.20).
if(!defined &header){
        *header = sub { return CGI::header(@_); };
        *path_info = sub { return CGI::path_info(@_); };
        *url = sub { return CGI::url(@_); };
        *script_name = sub { return CGI::script_name(@_); };
}
```

Adding a line in munin-cgi-html able to solve the issue.

```
sub header { return CGI::header(@_); }
```

But not sure what will be the impact of adding this line.
Is there anything specific configuration or package needs to install for Munin to work?

Answer (score 4):

The block on the bottom is importing symbols from CGI. Unfortunately, you are trying to use `header` before executing this block to import it. You need to execute the imports before all uses of `header` and such.

---

Note that

```perl
*header = sub { return CGI::header(@_); };
```

is better written as

```perl
*header = \&CGI::header
```

as it avoids a needless extra sub call.

---

Note that you can ask CGI.pm to export those symbols for you. Instead of manually importing the symbols, you can simply use either of following:

```perl
use CGI qw( header path_info url script_name );
```

```perl
use CGI qw( :cgi );
```

No need to clunckily import the symbols yourself.

Comment: You should probably mention that once the import is done correctly, that entire `if (!defined &header) {...}` block can be discarded.

Comment: @tobyink I wasn't fully awake when I answered. I have rewritten my Answer to provide a better answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks, that really worked. But what I am looking for Is whether am I missing any configuration/perl module in Munin installation with respect to perl. Since the particular munin-cgi-html file is part of Munin.